# Changing valuse of two textbox according to the combobox value change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

When selecting a value from a combo box the name and age textboxes should display the values by fetching the data from database.

Here the name is working fine, but i have no idea how to get display the age also

```
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <script src="jquerylib.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form>
   <table  border="0">
    <tr>           
     <td> 
        Select :
         //here the combobox selection
        <select name="name"  id="C_NAME"  >
          <option value="">Select a person:</option>
          <option value="1">SULOCHANA</option>
          <option value="2">COLOMBO</option>
          <option value="3">PILIYANDALA76</option>
         <option value="4">RAJAGIRIYA</option>
     </select>
  </td>   
</tr>  

<tr>  
  <td> 
     Display
    //display name
    <input name="dis_name" type="text"  id="display_name"   size="30" />
 //display age
    <input name ="age" type="text" id="age" />
 </td>
</tr>
```

`C_NAME` is the combo box id

```
   <script>
     $("select").change(function () {  
       var str =$("#C_NAME").val();

     if(str!=""){ 
        $.get("get_name.php", {id: str}, function(data){
        //get the value from the get_name.php file and asign to display_name text filed
       $("#display_name").val(data);});
     }`
     })
  .change();
 </script>
```

here is get_name.php

```
   <?php
     include('db.php');

    //getting the passed value using get

     $ID = intval($_GET['id']);

     $sql= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM system_user_tb WHERE id = '".$ID."'");
     $row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

     echo  $row['ID']." - " .$row['Login_name'];
   ?>
```

Comment: debug in developer tools and see if you are sending querystring id correctly. also debug your response there, this might help.

Comment: no the result is okey with single text box 
i have no idea about ajax
that why asking how to get the second value too

Comment: are you sure character ` is not a typo? in line `$("#display_name").val(data);});
     }``

Comment: yes, i want to know like you mention above, how to get display in age text box

Comment: the problem is i have no idea how to separate the two value that are submitted through the request

Comment: i don't understand what you want to achieve, i mean do you want to get two values from sever code like display name and age, or you have problem in your current code, aside from ` character i don't see anything wrong in your code

Comment: below answer is correct then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with PHP but I suggest you json format.
http://nz.php.net/json_encode
or if u don't want, use split function on returned string. For example:
return from get_name.php

```
echo  $row['ID']." # " .$row['Login_name']. " # " .$row['age'].;
```

and in js

```
function(data){

var data_array = data.split("#");
       $("#display_name").val(data_array[1]);
       $("#age").val(data_array[2]);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your delimiter to separate the age and name is `-` and first value is age and second value is name this will do the trick.

in your `function(data){`

```
$("#display_name").val(data.split("-")[0]);
$("#age").val(data.split("-")[1]);
```

Comment: next time use ajax and json do your homework on that

Comment: defnatly thnx again dude